# Development Tracking Suite - Individual Developer

Tags: content-management-system, tracking

I'm looking for a development tracking CMS, where I can list bugs, set milestones, features, etc. I'm an individual developer, so multiuser features are just a luxury for now. I'm also hoping to become more organized in my development methodology by using a development tracking CMS (rather than my own mix).

Please share some development tracking management systems (preferably free, running on the LAMP stack) for an independent developer!

(In other news - been gone from SO for a while, and I notice the Community Wiki tick has disappeared...)

Answer (score 1):

Bugzilla is probably one of the most prolific bug tracking systems.  I'm sure it can do most, if not all of what you want it to.

http://www.bugzilla.org/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/).  It integrates with SVN and other SCMs

http://trac.edgewall.org/

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has got a good page on comparison of issue tracking system: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [**TRAC**](http://trac.edgewall.org/) it is enhanced wiki and issue tracking system for software development projects. It is widely used with huge community, lots of "plugins". A common complaint is that it doesn't support multiple projects out-of-the-box, but you can add a plugin to help with that.

Notice that it provides an interface to  **Subversion** (or other version control systems). If you are SVN user you can post directly from SVN commits updates to issues. 
Take a peak at http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracProject.

It's not LAMP but it is easy to setup assuming you can run Python. I am using DreamHost and they have it in one click installs on their control panel. If you really want something with PHP then I guess Bugzilla but IMHO Trac is better.